# Update path color after it has been added to a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, path, controls

I have a canvas on which I have many paths. Sometime after having added the path to the canvas, I need to change the fill color of the path. How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried *anything* at all?

Comment: Find the path you want to change and change the color.

Comment: Yes, I have tried grabbing the path from the canvas and then taking that reference and updating it but nothing happens.

Comment: You're going to have to post more information in order for us to help you.  Where is the code you've tried,  what is not working about it.

Answer (score 1):

YourPath.Fill = Brushes.Blue;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill.aspx

Working example:

**Markup**

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="paths.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Path x:Name="myPath" Data="M101,190 C463,145 581.5,186.5 473.5,279.5 365.5,372.5 153.50002,345.50016 122.50001,271.49998 91.499996,197.4998 101,190 101,190 z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Margin="84.628,112.772,126.105,161.198" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black"/>
    <Button Content="Change Color" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="122" Margin="0,0,139,63.04" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code**

```
    namespace paths
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myPath.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        }
    }
}
```